Commutator of Normal Ordered Fields
Given the following scalar field:
$$
\begin{align}
\phi(x)&=\phi^+(x)+\phi^-(x)\\[0.2cm]
\phi^+(x)&= \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 E_p}}  a_p e^{-i p \cdot x}\\
\phi^-(x)&= \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 E_p}}  a_p^\dagger e^{i p \cdot x} 
\end{align}
$$
Is it true that $$[\phi^+(x_1),:\phi(x_2)\dots\phi(x_k):]=0~?$$
Here ": :" denotes normal ordering and we also have that $x_1^0\geq x_j^0$ for $j=1,...,k$

No. Check the case $k=2$.
